# Why is my pedal vibrating and making a noise when I start to brake?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, vibration, master-cylinder, brake-pedal

need some advice here. I have just gotten 2007 Mitsubishi Galant from relative with some braking problems. When I go to brake the PEDAL vibrates and make a loud noise. I have taken it too the shop a few times now. First they said brakes so has brand new brake now, but no change. Then it was said it was tires, got new tires and still acting up. Then they said roters, got new roters and still the same. Then they said master cylinder, put a brand new master cylinder on it yesterday and still doing it. Any ideas??

Comment: did you check the old tire? is it all of them worn out the same way or not? if it is worn out not the same, and if it loud noise coming from the tire it could be only bad wheel alignment. the master cylinder wouldn't make a loud noise. Tire rotor would make you drive like a drunk person or drive on a bumpy road.

Comment: Can you "record" the sound you say you hear in the brake pedal, and post somewhere we can get to it. You've already fired the parts canon several times. Before you start swapping suspension parts, you need to find out what is really at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like it could be the antilock brakes are activating prematurely. If this is the case you may have an ABS Warning light on in the dash. Or a check engine or brake warning light. The most common causes for this is a bad wheel speed sensor or connector or wiring. There's a few other things that can cause this failure but that's where I'd start. This condition can be easily diagnosed with a scanner and or multimeter. It is more economical for a diagnosis before repair as you are learning.